# Caching large arrays

Tags: php, arrays, performance, caching

I have following function:

```
function f($idx, $arr) {
    static $a;
    if ($a == NULL) {
        foreach ($arr as $v) {
            $key = $v['key'];
            if (!isset($a[$key])) {
                $a[$key] = array();
            }
            $a[$key][] = $v;
        }
    }

    return $a[$idx];
}
```

And the initial conditions are:

1. function `f()` is called many-many times in 1 request
2. `$arr` is always very large
3. `$arr` may differ in different function calls (low cardinality)
4. `$idx` differs almost in every function call (high cardinality)

And now I need to know, if `$arr` is already cached and if not, then create this "cached version", but keep also all previous arrays.

According to `2.` I'm not able to use `md5(serialize($arr))` to use it as identifier, so I need another way to determine that. Do you have any idea how to achieve such hight-performance caching functionality (let's say I'm not able to do any changes outside this function)?

Comment: So, instead of `$a[$idx]`, you're looking for `$a[$array_identifier][$idx]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not imperative that `$arr` not be modified, then I'd just add your optimized key access directly to it:

```
// note the argument has been changed to &$arr - we're passing by reference
function f($idx, &$arr) {
    if (empty($arr['___cached'])) {
        $arr['___cached'] = array();
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
            if ($k === '___cached') continue;
            if (!isset($arr['___cached'][$v['key']])) {
                $arr['___cached'][$v['key']] = array();
            }
            $arr['___cached'][$v['key']][] = $v;
        }
    }

    return $arr['___cached'][$idx];
}
```